# Parallels Plesk 12.0.18 - can not send mails using php while spf turned on

Tags: php, email, plesk, spf, spam-prevention

I recently upgraded my Parallels Plesk Panel from version 11 to 12.0.18 running on CentOS. And i noticed i can't send mails anymore using the php function "mail" while SPF-Spamprotection is enabled. I am using postfix as mailserver and mails get always rejected becaus of wrong helo (localhost).

This is what the log says:

```
spf filter[2532]: Starting spf filter...  
spf filter[2532]: Wrong HELO hostname: localhost  
/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[2465]: handlers_stderr: REJECT  
/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[2465]: REJECT during call 'spf' handler  
postfix/cleanup[2515]: 4E4D620AE2: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from    localhost[127.0.0.1]: 5.7.1 Command rejected; from=<> to=<xxx@xx.xx>  
postfix/cleanup[2515]: 4E4D620AE2: to=<xxx@xx.xx>, relay=none, delay=0.08, delays=0.08/0/0/0, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (Command rejected)
```

Turning off SPF Protection works and mails get delivered but thats not what i want. On previous version of Plesk everything worked just fine.
I already searched for a solution but found nothing useful.

Now my question is: how do i get this to work again?

Comment: http://major.io/2006/12/26/fixing-invalid-helos/

Comment: i already saw that page but that doesn't work and isn't a solution for my problem. my server sends a correct helo to others but rejects sending messages generated local with mail function. Writing "normal" mails is no problem and they got delivered. It's just php mail that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SPF-Records in your DNS settings for the domain you are sending from  i.ex:
xxx.xx  TXT v=spf1 +a +mx -all +a:your_host_name

Which means:

- all ips of the a-records are allowed to send mails under this
  domainname
- all ips of the mx-records are allowed to sent mails under this domainname
- domains send over hostname are allowed to sent mails under this domainname

---

At least if i remember correctly you can change the HELO domain for php mail function in php.ini

From php documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php):

```
; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=
```